# The parameter object is also changed when the method return the same type object

Tags: c#, oop

Please help me in this problem

I created an object Node

```
public Node(HashSet<string> _id, double _weight, List<string> _diff, int _depth, HashSet<string> _prefix, int _support)
{
    Id = _id;
    Weight = _weight;
    Diffset = _diff;
    Depth = _depth;
    Prefix = _prefix;
    Support = _support;
    Isleaf = false;
    Weightsup = _support*_weight;
}
```

I created a method like this and pass three parameter

```
public Node CreateTailNode(Node _a, Node _b, Double _minsup)
{
    Node _child = new Node();
    _child.Prefix = _a.Id;
    _child.Id = _a.Id.AddRange(_b.Id);
    _child.Depth = _a.Depth + 1;
    _child.Diffset = _a.Diffset.Except(_b.Diffset).ToList();
    _child.Weight = (_a.Weight + _b.Weight)/2;
    _child.Support = _a.Support - _child.Diffset.Count;
    _child.Weightsup = _child.Support*_child.Weight;
    if (_child.Weightsup < _minsup)
    {
        _child.Isleaf = true;
    }
    else
    {
        _child.Isleaf = false;
    }
    return _child;
}
```

After return _child i realize that Node _a.Prefix is also change and came to the same _child.Prefix

How can I create _child without change prefix of Node _a

Comment: _a and _b are reference types. Any change in those objects are present after calling this method. Review the "_a.Id.AddRange(_b.Id)" statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that `HashSet` is a reference type without value semantics, so copying the reference does not make a new copy of the contents; the reference copy ends up referencing the original object.

The solution is to make a copy of the `HashSet` before assigning it.

```
_child.Prefix = new HashSet<string>(_a.Id);
```

I'm not sure what you're intent is with _child.Id but I expect you'll have to do something similar with that:

```
_child.Id = new HashSet<string>(_a.Id);
_child.Id.AddRange(_b.Id);
```

The same logic would have to apply to any other reference types that you might be using; if you need a separate copy, you will have to make one explicitly.

Comment: A problems found in "child.Id = _a.Id.AddRange(_b.Id);"

Comment: Please send me instruction about create separate copy and make one explicitly, I don't understand

Comment: @TùngKiềuVũThanh The line `_child.Prefix = new HashSet<string>(_a.Id);` makes a separate copy.

Comment: I did it, It is correct. But  with the line    _child.Id = _a.Id.AddRange(_b.Id);    I changed to     child.Id = new HashSet<string>( _a.Id.AddRange(_b.Id););      still change _a.Id

Comment: @TùngKiềuVũThanh That's because you haven't used the code that I posted. `_a.Id.AddRange(_b.Id)` will obviously change `_a.Id`.